# Update query without where clause still updating different values for each row

Tags: sql, oracle

Context 
    Update query without where clause still updating different values for each row.
        How the below update query works?

```
    create table te--table creation
    (
    col1 varchar2(100),
    col2 varchar2(200))
    create table te1
    (
    col1 varchar2(100),
    col2 varchar2(200))

    insert into te (COL1, COL2) values ('1', 'ABC');
    insert into te (COL1, COL2) values ('2', 'XYZ');
    insert into te (COL1, COL2) values ('3', 'LMN');
    insert into te (COL1, COL2) values ('4', 'PQR');
    insert into te (COL1, COL2) values ('5', 'TTT');

    insert into te (COL1, COL2) values ('1', '');
    insert into te (COL1, COL2) values ('2', '');
    insert into te (COL1, COL2) values ('3', '');
    insert into te (COL1, COL2) values ('4', '');
    insert into te (COL1, COL2) values ('5', '');


    update te q
       set (q.col2) = (select tt.col2 from te1 tt where tt.col1 = q.col1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
update te q
       set (q.col2) = (select tt.col2 from te1 tt 
                       where tt.col1 = q.col1 
                         and tt.col2 is not null 
                         and LENGTH(tt.col2)>0);
```

UPDATE: your select has different results for the same col1 value (empty and not empty col2)

Comment: It will be more clear if you could have given the explanation as OP is asking for explanation.